# Mapping and object and send props to child does not return anything

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component and a child component.

The parent component receives an Object, I loop through it using `Object.keys` and I pass the props on each new item into the child component.

**However** I get the error that the child component does not render.

**Parent component**

```
const Parent = ({files}) => {
    Object.keys(files).map((file) => <Child file={file}  />)

};
```

**Child component**

```
function Child({file}) {
   console.log(item)
   return (<a> {item} </a>)
}
```

> > Error: Parent(...): Nothing was returned from render.

In addition, `console.log(item)` in my child component does not display anything. Therefore, I think my mapping is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return something from your `Parent` component.

```
const Parent = ({files}) => {
    return Object.keys(files).map((file) => <Child key={file} />)
};
```

Additionally, you won't need to access the `key` prop in your `Child` component, but you do need to actively pass in the `item` prop.  Not sure what you are expecting `item` to be, but something like `<Child key={file} item={file.item] />` or whatever it may be in your use case.

```
function Child({ item }) {
   console.log(item);
   return (<a> {item} </a>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you haven't passed in the `item` prop that the Child component depends on. Every 'attribute' on the JSX component equates to a property of the `props` object it will receive. You don't need to destructure off the `keys` prop either, since you aren't using it.

Second, your Parent component also needs to return something! A functional component's return value is the thing it renders. Here your Child is returning something to its Parent, who then does nothing with that value.

**Parent**

```
const Parent = ({files}) => {
    return Object.keys(files).map(file => 
        <Child key={file} item={file} />
    );
};
```

**Child**

```
function Child({item}) {
   console.log(item)
   return (<a> {item} </a>);
}
```